# Converting an ArrayList of Objects to JSON to be saved into SQLITE

Tags: android, json, sqlite, arraylist

I want to store an ArrayList of Objects (ArrayList) into a SQLITE database. I have read that this can be done. I believe that by converting the ArrayList to JSON and then save that to a String field in a SQLITE Table

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this conversion and how to convert it back to ArrayList afterwards.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Objects of a custom class ?

Comment: If you're saving a list, why not just save the list to a table such that each object is a row in the table? That would be a lot more efficient than storing and parsing JSON and I don't see any reason to do it otherwise.

Comment: yes. Each Object is a Custom Class Object

Comment: Trouble I have with saving all the information of the Objects Value is that each object has about 10 values and the ArrayList of about 150 Entry's. I have it running like that but it is very slow saving and then reading it all back

Comment: @JamesDudley, I doubt conversion to and from JSON every time will give you any performance boost.

Comment: why do you wan tto convert arraylist to jason when you can directly put arraylist objects in database

Comment: I was under the impression you cannot do that with SQLITE

Comment: Why not just use `serialization`? Other options would be to use ORMLite so make the whole procedure object oriented. I like using ORMLite as it makes the whole read / write DB easier. Also, if you want to stick to the JSON method consider using `Gson` since this is also bean oriented unlike the packaged JSON library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could help you:

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/588.html

This example shows how to convert `Collection (List/ArrayList)` to `JSON` than you can store your `JSON` string in `Sqlite` database.

It is also showing how to get `ArrayList` back from `JSON` string.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array of objects to a JSON string by hand using JSONStringer
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer.html

Jackson library can convert objects to/from JSON automatically
http://jackson.codehaus.org/
In particular, look at ObjectMapper.writeValue()
http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.6/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.Object)