# JSON serialisation of Model

Tags: java, android, json, serialization

In my app I save all my models using JSON. Saving my data converts my model to a `JSONObject` by putting all my variables in a `JSONObject` like:

```
public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put(JSON_ID, mId);
        json.put xxx
        ...

        return json;
}
```

Then using a `Writer` to create a .json file.

When I need to load my model I simply call its constructor like:

```
public MyModel(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        mId = json.getInt(JSON_ID);
        xxx
        ...
}
```

With the `JSONObject` I load from the previously created file. This works fine and I think it's the way to go.

However I can't seem to understand how to save data which is stored in a `ArrayList` since you can't put an `ArrayList` in a `JSONObject`. I tried creating a `JSONArray` and found that `JSONArray`s aren't serializable. I can work around this problem by converting my `JSONArray` to a `String` and putting that in my `JSONObject` to save. Then when I need the `ArrayList` I simple allocate a new `JSONArray` with the saved `String` but isn't there a better / more efficient way to save an `ArrayList`?

Comment: You could use annotations and let an Json parser that supports annotations do all the work for you, concerning converting Json file to objects and the other way arround. Jackson is a good example that many seems to be using https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations. It might save you some work :) Using that would automatically solve your problem I believe

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will check that out but first I would like to try it without any third party libraries.

Comment: This post might hold the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442416/converting-an-arraylist-of-objects-to-json-to-be-saved-into-sqlite

Comment: How about, creating a JSONArray from ArrayList and then converting it to string and then storing it in Sharedpreference instead of file ?

Comment: Yes so it all comes back to JSONArray / String conversion? I thought there should be a easier approach.

Comment: Why not write `JSONObject.toString()` to the file? Super easy.